# Jquery Working, but not?

Tags: jquery, conflict

I have a peculiar problem. I am trying to put a jquery simple hide, or simple anything in some pages, but it does not work.  I am sure that jquery works.

I tried:

```
$('.content').hide();
```

but `div`'s that have `class="content"` remain visible. So I tried:

```
jQuery(function($){
    $('.content').hide();
    alert('jQuery works');
});
```

In the second example I receive an alert that displays my message. But `div`'s with `class="content"` remain visible.

How can I deal with this?

---

> Thanks for all replies, when I render the div with class="conten"
>   outside the jQuery, the code works...

Comment: Sounds strange. Your code seems to be ok.

Comment: `$('.content')` probably doesn't match any elements on your page. Maybe there's a typo in the html?

Comment: Are you able to duplicate that behaviour with a demo at http://jsfiddle.net?

Comment: What does `alert(jQuery)` output?

Comment: Check out the `$(document).ready` and then implement this within it. May be your DOM is not able to load and the JS does

Comment: Your code seems to [work fine](http://jsfiddle.net/5nCnP/). My guess is that you've not included jquery.js or the URL is incorrect, or you've got an error elsewhere in your code.

Comment: `code alert($('.content').get(0)?'div .content found':'no div with class content found') `

Comment: @Matt the div that have class="content", is rendered trought jQuery...  Can it be the problem?

Comment: @WilliamdeCastro It shouldn't be a problem. Can you look at the html with Chrome Inspector or Firebug?

Comment: @nnnnnn too hard, the codes uses php inside JS

Comment: @Matt sure, code inspector from Chrome show the div like a HTML piece, but view source, dont show in DOM...

http://kemarisquare.com.br/faq?view=featured

view-source:http://kemarisquare.com.br/faq?view=featured

Comment: William type in $(".content").hide(); in the console. If it hides, then you are missing something in your code or have it in the wrong place.

Comment: Also, view source will not show content you have added or removed via jQuery, only what is present on page load.

Comment: So there's not deal with this page? Not possible to attach a jQuery behavior to a element rendered throgh jQuery ?

Comment: Yes there is, but it is not possible for us to debug this without a test-case. We do not have all the information. Please update your original post with a jsfiddle or simplified test-case.

Comment: Thanks for all replies, when I render the div with class="conten" outside the jQuery, the code works...

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".content").hide();
}
```

This code will ensure that content will only be hidden when jQuery is loaded and the page is ready.

Other things to check:

1. That you have an element with class of `content` on the page
2. You are actually loading jQuery
3. There are no other JS errors before this code. Check Firebug or Web Developer Console depending on which browser you are using.
4. That you don't have a competing library that has taken ownership of $. If so you'll need to use one of the methods to avoid code conflicting.

Comment: I too suspected the same stuff.

Comment: The code in the question already has a ready handler, and the OP said the `alert()` works, so presumably the `$('.content').hide()` line doesn't produce an error or execution would stop before the `alert()`.

Comment: nnnnn: that is why I included alternative possibilities.

Comment: I have not downvoted any answers Andrea. Please stay on topic or I will report you for going off it.

Answer (score 0):

Are you calling your function inside `jQuery(document).ready()` ? Do you have jQuery no conflict on ? Try this:

```
var $ = jQuery.noConflict();
$( 'document' ).ready( function(){
    $('.content').hide();
});
```

Comment: Yed dude, I have another jQuery codes run under nonconflict in this page

Answer (score -1):

Use `jQuery` instead of `$`

```
jQuery(function(){
    jQuery('.content').hide();
});
```

Comment: I tried yet, with no result, thx anyway dude
The downvote is not mine, I can't evaluate answers...